# why does this second code not require split()?

Tags: python, algorithm

Q) make A-B code

```
a, b = input()
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
print(a-b)
```

this code get valueerror if i dont put split function next to input

```
a,b,c=input();print(int(a)-int(c))
```

but above code dont need split()

why is that?

Comment: Don't know why you think the second option won't require split but it does & throws the same error the first one does.

Comment: Depends what input you're entering into the program, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: What do you mean by requiring split. They behave same for me.

Comment: umm in my code editor, second code works... so it is weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when unpacking an iterable, the number of variables must match the values input being assigned. it depends on the values you are trying to unpack from the input.
for instance,

```
a,b= input() #12
print(a). #1
print(b). #2
```

You can easily unpack.
However if you pass in more values than variable you will get an error.

```
a,b= input() #123
print(a) #1
print(b) # error!!
```

To avoid that you can use the the '*'

```
a,*b= input() #1234567
print(a) #1
print(b) #[2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what your input is. You need to recognise that this is multiple assignment. Your input is `str` and it is unpacked into variables. The number of variables must be equal to elements in the sequence you unpack.

So for the first snippet

- if you enter 2 digits, e.g. `31` it will work as you expect. `a` will be equal to `3` (after conversion with `int()`) and `b` will be equal to `1`.
- if you enter more than 2 digits, e.g. `3 1`, it will fail because, `a` will be `3` and `b` will be `' '` and there will be no name to bind `1` to. If there is space and you use `split()` it will split the string at space and you will get 2-element list and then there will be no error because you have 2 names - `a` and `b` and expects 2 values.

for the second snippet

- it will work as expected if you enter `3 1` (a=3, b=' ' and c=1 and will fail if you enter `31` because (a=3, b=1, and there is no value for c).

Answer (score 0):

you can change the code to this simple one so that no error occurs.!

```
 a = int(input('a'))
 b = int(input('b'))
 print(a-b)
```